# Links Not Working in Floated div

Tags: css, html

I have looked all over and can't seem to find the answer. I have links inside a div class that is floated. I have 2 div floated one left one right. I know I have read something about link is 100% width covering up things but can't seem to get it to work. In the JC div's links from 9-15 will work links from 1-8 won't plus in he div .heading1Text links don't work. Can make links a certain color and size but that's all.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">

     <div class="logo">
             <a href="http://badboyzbailbondsks.com/index.html" title="Return to the Home Page">
              <img src="images/bad-boyz-bail-bonds-topeka-ks-header.png" width="100%">

              <div class="call">Call Now</div>
              <div class="days">24hrs / 7 Days A Week</div>
              <div class="number">785-640-7383</div>
              <div class="town">Topeka, KS</div>
              </a>
     </div>


     <div id="nav">
           <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li class="help"><a href="help.html">How Can We Help</a></li>
           <li class="faq"><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li>
           <li class="resource"><a href="resource.html">Resources</a></li>
           <li class="forms"><a href="forms.html">Forms</a></li>
           <li class="tests"><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
           <li class="contact"><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>

    </div> 

</div>

<div id="content">

      <div class="info">           
        <div class="heading1">Judicial Courts</div><br />
                <div class="heading1Text">Here is a list of the Judicial Court Offices with address' and phones numbers to each Court office. For Municipal Court Address' Click this link - <a href ="municipal.html">MUNICIPAL COURTS</a>. If you need directions to the Court address, please click get directions below the court your looking for. For links to the forms to fill out to help the process of getting your loved one out as fast as possible see links on right side or <a href="forms.html">GO HERE</a>.
                </div>

    </div>    

                <br /><br />
        <div class="court">          
                <div class="courtsType">Judicial Courts</div>

                <br /><br />

                <div class="jc1">
                      <div class="courts">Atchison County</div>
                        <li>425 N. 5th St., Atchison, KS 66002</li>
                        <li>Phone: 913-367-7400</li>
                        <li>Fax: 913-367-1171</li>
                        <li class="directions"><a href="municipal.html">Directions</a></li>
                </div>        
               <div class="jc2">
                      <div class="courts">Coffey County</div>
                        <li>110 S. 6th St. Ste 102, Burlington, KS 66839</li>
                        <li>Phone: 620-364-8628</li>
                        <li>Fax: 620-364-8535</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
               </div>
               <br />
              <div class="jc3">
                      <div class="courts">Dickinson County</div>
                        <li>109 E. 1st St., Abilene, KS 67410</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-263-3142</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-263-4407</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
              </div>
              <div class="jc4">
                      <div class="courts">Douglas County</div>
                        <li>111 E. 11th St., Lawrence, KS 66024</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-832-5256</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-832-5174</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
               </div>
               <br />
               <div class="jc5">
                      <div class="courts">Franklin County</div>
                        <li>301 S. Main St., Ottawa, KS 66067</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-242-6000</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-242-5970</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
                </div>        
               <div class="jc6">
                      <div class="courts">Geary County</div>
                        <li>138 E. 8th St., Junction City, KS 66441</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-762-5221</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-762-4420</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
               </div>
               <br />
              <div class="jc7">
                      <div class="courts">Jackson County</div>
                        <li>400 New York St., Holton, KS 66436</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-364-2191</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-364-3804</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
              </div>
              <div class="jc8">
                      <div class="courts">Jefferson County</div>
                        <li>300 Jefferson St., Oskaloosa, KS 66066</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-863-2461</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-863-2369</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
               </div>
               <br />
              <div class="jc9">
                      <div class="courts">Lyon County</div>
                        <li>430 Commercial St. Emporia, KS 66801</li>
                        <li>Phone: 913-367-7400</li>
                        <li>Fax: 620-341-3497</li>
                        <li class="directions"><a href="municipal.html">Directions</a>        </li>
              </div>
              <div class="jc10">
                      <div class="courts">Miami County</div>
                        <li>120 S. Pearl St., Paola, KS 66071</li>
                        <li>Phone: 913-294-3326</li>
                        <li>Fax: 913-294-2535</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
              </div>
              <br />
              <div class="jc11">
                      <div class="courts">Osage County</div>
                        <li>717 Topeka Ave., Lyndon, KS 66451</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-828-4514</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-828-4704</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
               </div>
              <div class="jc12">
                      <div class="courts">Pottawatomie County</div>
                        <li>106 Main St., Westmoreland, KS 66549</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-457-3392</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-457-2107</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
              </div>
              <br/>
              <div class="jc13">
                      <div class="courts">Riley County</div>
                        <li>100 Courthouse Plaza, Manhattan, KS 66505</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-537-6364</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-537-6328</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li> 
               </div>
              <div class="jc14">
                      <div class="courts">Shawnee County</div>
                        <li>200 SE 7th St., Topeka, KS 66603</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-233-8200</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-291-4908</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
              </div>
              <br />
              <div class="jc15">
                      <div class="courts">Wabaunsee County</div>
                        <li>215 Kansas St., Alma, KS 66401</li>
                        <li>Phone: 785-765-2406</li>
                        <li>Fax: 785-765-2487</li>
                        <li class="directions">Directions</li>
              </div>

              <br /><br />

       </div>

             <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

      <div class="disclaimer">
          <div class="dis"><b><u>Disclaimer:</u></b><div class="disText">Bad Boyz Bail Bonds is not responsible for the courts decision on bail eligibility, bail amounts or any other legal issues concerning the defendants charges or case.</div></div> 
      </div> 

     <div id="rtCol">
          <div id="homeImg"><img src="images/court.png" width="100%"></div>
          <div id="homeInfo"><img src="images/info.png" width="100%"></div> 
          <div id="formList"><img src="info.png" width="100%">
                 <div class="fill"><b><u>Fill Out Your Forms In Advance</u></b></div>
                 <div class="before">Before Court Begins</div>
                 <div class="promise">Promissory Note</div>
                 <div class=""></div>
                 <div class=""></div>
                 <div class=""></div>
         </div>  
         <div id="muni">For Municipal Court Address' Click this link - <a href="municipal.html">MUNICIPAL COURTS</a></div>      
     </div>

  </div>



     <div id="footer">

          <div class="footerImg">
               <img src="images/footerImg.png" width="100%">
          </div>

       <ul id="btmNav">
           <li class="btmHome"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li class="btmHelp"><a href="help.html">How Can We Help</a></li>
           <li class="btmFaq"><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li>
           <li class="btmResource"><a href="resource.html">Resources</a></li>
           <li class="btmForms"><a href="forms.html">Forms</a></li>
           <li class="btmTests"><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
           <li class="btmContact"><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>

      </ul>

      <div id="visa"><img src="images/visa.png" width="60%"></div>
      <div id="mc"><img src="images/mc.png" width="60%"></div>
      <div id="discover"><img src="images/discover.png" width="60%"></div>
      <div id="cash"><img src="images/cash.png" width="60%"></div>



      <div class="copy">&copy;BadBoyzBailBondsKS.com - 2014</div> 

      <div class="by">Design By Benwa Designs</div> 



   </div>
```

CSS file:

```
 #wrapper
{
max-width:970px;
padding-top:1%;
margin:auto;
}

#header
{
max-width:970px;
margin:auto;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.logo
{
position:relative;
}

.call
{
position:absolute;
top:6%;
right:4%;
color:rgb(255,0,0);
font-size:2em;
text-decoration:underline;
text-align:center;
width:19%
 }

 .days
 {
position:absolute;
top:36%;
right:0.5%;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
font-size:1em;
text-align:center;
width:26%;
 }

.number
{
position:absolute;
top:53%;
right:1%;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
font-size:2em;
width:25%;
text-align:center;
}

.town
{
position:absolute;
top:79%;
right:6%;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
font-size:1em;
width:15%;
text-align:center;
}

#nav
{
list-style:none;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
line-height:26px;
background-color: rgb(51,0,255);
text-align:center;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}

#nav li
{
display:inline-block;
font-size:18px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
padding:0px 10px;
}

#nav li:hover
{
height:26px;
background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}

#nav li a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#content
{
position:relative;
max-width:970px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
margin:auto;
}

.info
{
width:65%;
}

#rtCol
{
position:absolute;
float:right;
width:100%;
top:2%;
right:1.5%;
}
#homeImg
{
width:25%;
float:right;
clear:right;
padding-bottom:1%;
}

#homeInfo
{
width:25%;
float:right;
clear:right;
padding-bottom:1%;
}

 #formList
{
position:relative;
width:25%;
float:right;
clear:right;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

.fill
{
position:absolute;
right:5.9%;
color:rgba(51,19,255,1);
font-size:16px;
top:4%;
padding:0 1px 0 1px;
 }

 .before
 {
position:absolute;
right:45%;
color:rgba(51,19,255,1);
font-size:16px;
top:15%;
padding:0 1px 0 1px;
}

.promise
{
position:absolute;
right:53%;
color:rgba(51,19,255,1);
font-size:16px;
top:25%;
padding:0 1px 0 1px;
}

 #muni
 {
position:relative;
font-size:18px;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
text-align:center;
float:right;
clear:right;
width:25%;
 }

 #muni a
 {
text-decoration:none;
color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

#muni a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.heading1
{
padding-top:55px;
padding-left:20px;
font-size:32px;
color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.heading1Text
{
font-size:16px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
padding-left:20px;
}

.directions a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:rgba(255,255,0,1);
}

.directions a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.court
 {
 width:65%
 }

.courtsType
{
font-size:22px;
color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
text-decoration:underline;
text-align:center;
}

.courts
{
font-size:16px;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
text-decoration:underline;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.directions
{
color:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}

.jc1
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
width:32%;
}

.jc2
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc3
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.jc4
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc5
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.jc6
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc7
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.jc8
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc9
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.jc10
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc11
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.jc12
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc13
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.jc14
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
text-align:center;
}

.jc15
{
list-style:none;
color:rgba(0,255,0,1);
float:left !important;
padding:0px 50px 0px 30px;
text-align:center;
}

.dis
{
font-size:14px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
margin:auto;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
float:none;
}

.disText
{
font-size:13px;
}

#footer
{
position:relative;
max-width:970px;
margin:auto;
}

.footerImg
{
position:relative;
}

#btmNav
{
position:absolute;
top:5%;
list-style:none;
width:63%;
left:18.5%;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}

#btmNav li
{
display:inline-block;
font-size:16px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
padding:0px 10px;
}

#btmNav li a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#btmNav li a:hover
{
color:rgb(255,255,255);
text-decoration:underline;
}

#visa
{
position:absolute;
left:1%;
top:5.5%;
width:5%;
text-align:center;
}

#mc
{
position:absolute;
left:8%;
top:5.5%;
width:5%;
text-align:center;
}

#discover
{
position:absolute;
right:8%;
top:5.5%;
width:5%;
text-align:center;
}

#cash
{
position:absolute;
right:1%;
top:5.5%;
width:5%;
text-align:center;
 }

.by
{
position:absolute;
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
font-size:10px;
text-align:center;
right:1%;
width:14%;
bottom:10%;
 }

.copy
{
position:absolute;
font-size:14px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
text-align:center;
bottom:10%;
left:37.3%;
width:25%;
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem a bit?

Comment: not sure what the question is asking since all the <a> links are working EXCEPT where you don't have <a> tags.

Comment: Try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and a tip: you're repeating a lot of CSS code, try to define an .odd and .even class, so you'll use onlye 2 classes instead of 15 (for .jcxx elements)

Comment: @j08691  links in the .headingText1 div don't work and links in the JC divs from 1-8 don't work.

Comment: @lovetostrike  I know what your saying  tried putting <a> tags everywhere they need to be but like I said didn't work in the .heading1Text div and in the JC divs. That's why I don't have them there now.

Comment: there are two links inside heading1Text: municipal.html and forms.html. Yes? I can click all of them. It would take me to file not found error, of course I don't have those files. What error are you getting now or just can't click?

Comment: Yes 2 different links. Site isn't live so you wont go to a page. I can not click on them don't change on hover etc. Something to do with the floated div rtCol I know but confused on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

for the anchor elements in `div` with class `.heading1Text`, they are being cover over by `div` with id **"rtCol"** so click does not happen on anchor tag it happens on rtCol div and i didn't see any anchor tags in `li`'s jc2,jc3,jc4 etc.
put following code on your html page's head for getting info about where you are actually clicking

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(event){console.log("clicked on >>");console.log(event.target)});
});
</script>
```

from your comment what i can suggest is do this change width of **rtCol** to **250px** and width's of **homeImg, homeInfo, formList, muni** to 100%

Comment: I know there are no anchor tags in the jc1 etc thru jc7 because they didn't work. I know when I try to click on a link in the .heading1Text the rtCol highlights. trying to figure out how to get the links to work. I know it has to do with a floated div but confused on how to get them to work.

Comment: try re-arranging your CSS properties as mentioned in answer

Comment: I did figure things out. had the div on the rtCol 100%. Lowered it to 28% now everything works fine.